# javascript random gen nr + loops

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an program where it randomly picks 10 questions out of X questions(got 14 random ones written at the moment) without it picking the same questions again but i've been stuck for 4 hours on this junk.

My problem is with "randomNumbers()" function. This function generates random number (which marks the question respectively) and then checks if the numberArray already has generated number. If it doesnt, the number is supposed to be pushed to array.

I think I figured out the problem to be  ## VERSION 1 ##    for-loops if/else conditions. Any help ? :(

//edit, is while (true) correct way to handle this?

// dont mind ##VERSION 2##   it was the first way I tried solving the problem.

(a lot of console logs to determine the bug :P )

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Testimiskeskkond</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="startQuiz()">Alusta testimist</button>
    <div id="question1"></div>
    <div id=questions></div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var amountOfQuestions = 11;
var questionCounter = 0;
var numberArray = new Array();


var questions = new Array();
questions[0] = 'Mitu kassi elab P2rnus?',
questions[1] = 'Mis on kassi nimi?',
questions[2] = 'Mida kass teeb?',
questions[3] = 'Millal kass syndis?',
questions[4] = 'Mitu hammast kassil on?',
questions[5] = 'Mitu kyynt on kassil?',
questions[6] = 'Mitu k6rva on kassil?',
questions[7] = 'Mis v2rvi on kass?',
questions[8] = 'Tooli v2rvus?',
questions[9] = 'Laua suurus?',
questions[10] = 'Lemmik jook?',
questions[11] = 'Lemmik s88k?',
questions[12] = 'Raamatupoe nimi?',
questions[13] = 'Viinapoe nimi?';


function startQuiz() {
var setQuestions = "";

while (questionCounter < amountOfQuestions) {
    var random = randomNumbers();
    console.log(random + "appppppi");

    if (questionCounter < amountOfQuestions) {
        setQuestions += questions[random] + "<br>";
        questionCounter += 1;
    } else {
        setQuestions += questions[random];
        questionCounter += 1;
    }

}

$('#questions').html(setQuestions);

}

function randomNumbers() {
var arrLength = numberArray.length;

while (true) {
    console.log(arrLength);

    var randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * 14);
    console.log(randomNr + " tereeeeeeeeee");

    /*
    ######################
    ########### VERSION 1
    ######################*/

    if (arrLength == 0) {
        console.log("pppppppppppp");
        numberArray.push(randomNr);
        break;
    } else if (arrLength == 1) {
        console.log("oooooooooooo");
        if (numberArray[0] == randomNr) {
            console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrr");
            numberArray.push(randomNr);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength-1; i++) {
            console.log("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
            if (numberArray[i] == randomNr) {
                console.log("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
                continue;
            } else {
                console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
                numberArray.push(randomNr);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    /*
    ######################
    ########### VERSION 2
    ######################

    if (arrLength > 0) {
        console.log("oooooooooooo");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
            console.log("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
            if (numberArray[i] == randomNr) {
                console.log("qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq");
                continue;
            } else {
                console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzzz")
                numberArray.push(randomNr);
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("pppppppppppp");
        numberArray.push(randomNr);
        break;

    } */
}


return randomNr;
}
```

Comment: You're over-engineering.   1) init an array 2) generate a random number 3) if its not in array, push it 4) check array length; quit when there are enough.  Repeat from step 2. All that can be in a `while` checking for the length. I don't see the need for nested loops. Don't `while(true)` unless you intend an infinite loop; make the loop say what it's looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let selectionCount = 10;
let randomQuestions = [];

while(randomQuestions.length < selectionCount) {
   let randomNr = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionList.length);

   if(!randomQuestions.includes(randomNr)) {
       randomQuestions.push(randomNbr);
   }
}
```

Comment: wow, that was horrible of me :X  
i used includes instead of contains.  
Thanks!